# How to pass object from trigger to orchestra and activity functions

Tags: azure, azure-durable-functions

I have HTTP trigger which invokes orchestra function. In HTTP trigger function I receive json string which I deserialize into object . However I have no idea how to pass this object to orchestra function or activity functions.

I have tried to include it as parameter of orchestra function but it gives me error

HTTP trigger

```
#load "../Shared/jsonObject.csx"
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
HttpRequestMessage req,
DurableOrchestrationClient starter,
string functionName,
ILogger log)
{

HttpContent requestContent = req.Content;
string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
jsonObject bsObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonObject>      (jsonContent);  

// Pass the function name as part of the route 
string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Orchestra", bsObj);

log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
}
```

Orchestra function

```
#load "../Shared/jsonObject.csx"
[FunctionName("Orchestra")]
public static async void Run(DurableOrchestrationContext context)
{   

var output = await context.CallActivityAsync<int>("checkConditions", bsObj);
}
```

Activity functionn  not implemented yet

```
#load "../Shared/jsonObject.csx"
public static string Run(jsonObject bsObj)
{
return  "done";

}
```

[Error] run.csx(19,74): error CS0103: The name 'bsObj' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 4):

Please try running the below code

HTTP Trigger function.

```
    [FunctionName("HttpTriggerCSharp")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")]HttpRequestMessage req,
        [OrchestrationClient]DurableOrchestrationClient starter,
        ILogger log)`
    {

        HttpContent requestContent = req.Content;
        string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        JObject bsObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonContent);
        // Pass the function name as part of the route 
        string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Orchestra", bsObj);
        log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");
        return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
    }
```

Orchestration Function

```
        [FunctionName("Orchestra")]
    public static async Task RunOrchestrator(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        var bsObj = context.GetInput<JObject>();
        var output = await context.CallActivityAsync<JObject>("checkConditions", bsObj);
    }
```

Activity Function

```
        [FunctionName("checkConditions")]
    public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] JObject bsObj, ILogger log)
    {
        //Assign input value to any variable
        var json = bsObj;
        //Logic of the code
        return "done";
    }
```

I have referenced this [doc](https://azure.github.io/azure-functions-durable-extension/api/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.DurableOrchestrationClient.html) for durable functions extention and this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook) for HTTP Triggered functions.

Comment: if in activity function I wanna access object fields do I just access them like I would normally would?

Comment: Yes, it will be normal. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: it gives me "Executed 'Functions.checkConditions' (Failed, Id=d1d20188-d990-4719-a8db-863486623dc0)

Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error

Comment: Can you update the question with the new code? So that it will be easy for debugging.

Comment: i figured it out and I will update it here as soon as I get time. thanks for help

Comment: in RunOrchestrator i get Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NotSupportedException: The collection type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is abstract, an interface, or is read only, and could not be instantiated and populated. Path: